# I can't install axios with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, operating-system

I'm currently working on a express app that will use IGDB's api and I was going to use axios, but whenever I installing axios with npm I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /home/sami/videoGamesAPI/node_modules/axios
npm ERR! dest /home/sami/videoGamesAPI/node_modules/.axios-JBGmzY38
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/home/sami/videoGamesAPI/node_modules/axios' -> '/home/sami/videoGamesAPI/node_modules/.axios-JBGmzY38'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/home/sami/videoGamesAPI/node_modules/axios' -> '/home/sami/videoGamesAPI/node_modules/.axios-JBGmzY38'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/sami/videoGamesAPI/node_modules/axios',
npm ERR!   dest: '/home/sami/videoGamesAPI/node_modules/.axios-JBGmzY38'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/sami/.npm/_logs/2023-03-27T23_38_55_290Z-debug-0.log
```

I tested this on a dummy project and I get the same exact error. I also tried running this code as the administrator but I get the same results. I also tried to install an update for npm but that was rejected as well, along with the same exact permission error. I see the `npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/home/sami/videoGamesAPI/node_modules/axios' -> '/home/sami/videoGamesAPI/node_modules/.axios-JBGmzY38'` line but I didn't want to rename anything yet out of fear of messing something up. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi there! It looks like the path `/home/sami/videoGamesAPI/node_modules` has some permission settings that prevents changes for the user running the `npm i` command. You can check the owner and permissions over /home/sami/videoGamesAPI directory using `ls -la` from the command line. (btw its not the ideal solution but running `sudo npm install` should work I guess...). Also you can remove de node_modules folder an try to run the `npm i` command again.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me! I still have one more slight problem though. I mentioned in the original post that I was also getting this error when trying to update npm in the root. Any ideas what's going on there?

Comment: Great! If you are trying to update npm for the root user maybe you want to try something like `sudo npm install -g npm@latest`. I guess that as it's a global installation it could be done with sudo. I used `latest` as an example...more info here -> https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm

Answer (score 0):

The folder has some write permission, you should fix it first and
`sudo npm install` since it will run under root permissions.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/829537/how-to-change-owner-of-folder-to-current-user-recursively